# Most efficient solution for printing large amount of data

Tags: vb.net, printing, report

For example, there are 10-12 forms and in everyone of them there are between 5-20 panels with datagridview and some text. Content of every panel should be printable if there is any data in their DGV. 
What would be easiest solution for printing data, should I make report for every one of those panels or there is some better/easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always create reports for anything you want to print. There are other options but they often take longer (PrintDocument) or they're harder to maintain (PrintDocument) or they're not very professional (screen/form print) or they only work until you get more data than what is visible on the users screen (grids with screen/form print).

Of coarse there are other options like sending the info to MS Word and telling it to print but that requires the end user has MS Word installed. Some try to create PDF documents and either fail or wish they hadn't.

Don't re-invent the wheel. Reports were created for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid of that answer. It seems that for this application I'll have make 100-150 different reports, so I thought that I could somehow avoid that and maybe print the whole panel, but then again I don't know what printing control I'll have (I don't know much about printing capabilities of VS).